# Is possible to query events attributes on tempo by traceQL

Tags: grafana, tempo

I can't query the exception and error message in events sending from Opentelemetry, I studied official instrument, seems like that only can do span and resource two attributes, I wonder that if  anyone knows?

tried query

```
{ .exception.type = "StandardError" }
{ events.exception.type = "StandardError" }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvMWe.png)

can query exception and error message